# Freemaker conditionality inside loop

Tags: java, email, templates, freemarker

I am currently having this in my template:

```
<#list replyList as reply>
    <#if true>
        XXXXXXXXXX
    <#/if>
     ${reply.enteredText}
</#list>
```

But this returns me the following error:
EmailTemplateProcessor:207 - Freemarker Exception
freemarker.core.ParseException: Encountered < /#list > at line 31, column 5 in yyy.ftl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `<#/if>`, which should be `</#if>`. (Unfortunately, `<#/` is just static text in the long existing syntax, so it doesn't give an error... backward compatibility.)

Comment: noticed earlier forgot to delete the question.. thanks anyway @ddekany!!